# How to configure requestTimeout with Spring Boot and Netty as HTTP server?

Tags: spring-boot, netty

How to configure requestTimeout with Spring Boot and Netty as HTTP server?

I can see that netty offers the requestTimeout option (https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#http-server-request-timeout) but Spring Boot seems not to allow to configure it via configuration. Is there any reason for that? How can I configure it then?

Answer (score 0):

It can be customized by doing the following. However, I don't understand why Spring Boot does not provide a way to configure it out of the box.

```
    @Component
    public class MyNettyWebServerCustomizer
            implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

        @Override
        public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer.requestTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
        }
    }
```